# SHA-512 validation on Python

Tags: python, regex, hash

How to check whether the sha-512 hash is valid?
Wrote the following code

```
 def is_pwd(passwd):
    result = re.findall(r'[a-f0-9]{128}', passwd)
    if result:
        print "Valid"
    else:
        print "NOT a Valid"
```

But when I pass the hash:
3c9909afec25354d551dae21590bb26e38d53f2173b8d3dc3eee4c047e7ab1c1eb8b85103e3be7ba613b31bb5c9c36214dc9f14a42fd7a2fdb84856bca5c44c2''''!@#

Return - VALID

Thx.

Comment: `findall`?  What did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

If you definitely want to use `regex`, you should use `re.match` instead:

```
def is_pwd(passwd):
    result = None
    try: result = re.match(r'^\w{128}$', passwd).group(0)
    except: pass
    return result is not None
```

This method returns `True` for a valid password and `False` for an invalid one.

#### Breakdown:

1. `^` - Checks from the start of the string
2. `\w{128}` - Checks for exactly 128 occurrences of an alphanumeric character
3. `$` - Confirms the end of the string (i.e. if you had more than 128 alphanums, it would return False)

Comment: `\w` is too permissive. We want hex digits, not all word characters. Also, why the try-except? It's needless; we can simply check whether we got a match or None.